# JVM space exhausted when building a project through gradle

Tags: java, gradle, gradlew

Receiving error message when building a project through gradle

> Expiring Daemon because JVM Tenured space is exhausted

Answer (score 74):

This means the JVM doesn't have enough memory to compile the Java files. There's a couple of steps that can be taken.

1. Run `./gradlew clean`, which will remove everything including leftovers from previous builds which are no longer relevant.
2. Run `./gradlew --stop`, killing other gradle daemons which may be taking up memory.
3. Allocate more memory. This can be done by adding the following to the `gradle.properties` file.

> org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xms128m -Xmx1024m -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled